# Visa bans on Iranians according to new presidential executive order

Tags: usa, visa, marriage, greencard

I am a green card holder. My family and I migrated to USA with EB-5 program. Now I'm married and my wife is in Iran. We started the process of getting a green card for her and have been waiting for one year and four months. We also have Homeland Security's confirmation and we were just waiting for the visa to get issued.

Now what should we do?

Each of us is in another part of the world. We planned our lives around migrating here. I left my university and school in Iran to come here. We sold our house and everything to invest here. Our decision wasn't illegal as the rules were that if a green card holder decided to get married he or she can bring their spouse.

[Text](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/01/27/executive-order-protecting-nation-foreign-terrorist-entry-united-states) of the executive order.

Comment: Also, the bans are going to be more specific in many cases, and broad in others. Obviously those who have any connection to terrorism are out. But also those who have practiced any violence against women or engaged in anti-American rhetoric are out, irrespective of their religion. It's not going to be a simple retroactive ban.

Comment: A link to the actual information (the executive order) might be helpful

Comment: People are [already being denied entry and denied boarding at airports](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/28/us/refugees-detained-at-us-airports-prompting-legal-challenges-to-trumps-immigration-order.html) due to this order.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your wife will not be able to come for at least 90 days, maybe longer. The ban affects both immigrants and nonimmigrants.

Comment: And it might be unwise to visit her in Iran (or anywhere outside the USA).